# tabbable panes stopped working in IE 11 after upgrade to bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I have HTML page with some inline svg. Clicking links in svg supposed to show hidden panes. It worked fine in bootstrap 3 with all my browsers (firefox, edge, ie11, chrome). After upgrade to bootstrap 4 it stopped working only in IE11 (no effect on link click). Test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 -20 10 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" height="400">
        <g class="nav">
            <a href="#nav-tab1" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-item nav-link">
                <text x="82" y="30">link1</text>
            </a>
            <a href="#nav-tab2" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-item nav-link">
                <text x="82" y="70">link2</text>
            </a>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-tab1">
            <p>Tab panel ONE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="nav-tab2">
            <p>Tab panel awesome TWO</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: I try to test your code with Chrome and IE 11 browser and found that it is giving similar output in both browsers. Here is my testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/W42vHDLn/113.gif I suggest you to again try to run your above sample with IE to check the result. Also inform me if I misunderstood anything from your above description. I will try to correct myself. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: clicking links does nothing in IE11. in chrome clicking link1 shows tab panel 1 and clicking link 2 shows panel 2 as expected.

Comment: Is my testing result giving desired output in IE ? Check whether JavaScript is enabled in your IE browser or not.

Comment: you testing results are not giving desired result. seems you are not correctly supplied bootsrap and jquery files specified in link and script tags.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the issue again and I am able to produce the issue with your code.

I try to refer the documentation of Bootstrap and try to run the sample with Bootstrap 4 and it worked fine with IE 11.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
       <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 -20 10 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" height="400">
   
            <g class="nav">
    
    <div class="nav-item">
                   <a href="#pills-home" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-item nav-link">
      <text x="82" y="30">link1</text></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
     
     <a href="#pills-profile" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-item nav-link">
      <text x="82" y="70">link2</text></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
     
     <a href="#pills-contact" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-item nav-link">
      <text x="82" y="140">link2</text>
     </a>
    </div>
    
            </g>
        </svg>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">This is HOME tab...</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">This is PROFILE tab...</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">This is CONTACT tab...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Reference:

[Bootstrap Navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)

Further you can try to modify the above example as per your requirement and let us know if you have any further questions.

Comment: clickable links must be positioned with svg coordinates, its a key requirement for me. html unordered list do not works for me in this regard

Comment: As I said it is working with SVG too. Can you please try to test it on your side? Then let me know about your results.

Comment: You can not position links when they are inside li tags inside parent ul tag. It was my first attempt to replace g tag with ul tag. It works, but there are no way to position individual links. Even if you place them in (svg-)text element, they are placed on page side by side, ignoring specified coordinates.

Comment: I see same result: links are positioned side by side ignoring specified coordinates.

Comment: I again modified the example in my answer to display the links by coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but links still do not respect coordinates. Postions are fixed. Try to postion them diagonally for example.

Comment: I think what you are telling is a different issue. Your original issue was Bootdtrap 4 tabbable pane not working in IE 11. which I show you that it is working. I suggest you to create a new thread for that position related issue.

Comment: My positioning works fine. In all browsers. In all versions of bootstrap. But after upgrading to bootsrap 4 panes stops showing only in IE11. You was able to reproduce issue. Do i violated any bootstrap's rules?

Comment: What I reproduced (no effect on link click) as mentioned in original post. Which looks working from my above example. Your new question is why positioning of your links is not working in IE. For that I suggest you to close this thread and create a new thread for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Your above example misrepresent my case. You fixed one thing (not showing) while broke another (no respect to specified coordinates). And you suggested positioning do not work in ANY browser.

Comment: You need to scroll to get the result if you are checking in snippet. Based on my testing result. If you remove the nav-item div then it fix the position issue but it breaks the link. To make the link work you have to add div with nav-item. You can provide the feedback to bootstrap about this issue.